# How to store custom info in Salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, custom-object, lightning-apps

I am working on a salesforce APP where I need to store below information.
1) App specific secret token. Should be only visible to Administrator
2) Logs of activities performed on APP. Need to show in "Past Activities" screen of App.

What would be best way to achieve above mentioned #1 & #2

Also, I should be able to bundle above structure while packaging my APP (to list on Salesforce APP Exchange).

I am using Apex for backend and Lightning App to build APP UI.

PS: I am java developer and new to Salesforce. Apologies if my doubt sound stupid :)

Comment: for #1, you can use custom setting which will be only visible to Administrator and you can set it the values while creating the package as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Storing Sensitive Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Storing_Secrets) for more information, but the basic answer is to use a Protected Custom Setting. You can then control who can see the values by writing a Visualforce page or Lightning Component, as well as validating the input to make sure its valid data (whatever that means to your application). You can bundle Custom Fields and Custom Objects in your package as well, and from there, it's trivial to make your own custom logging scheme.

One important thing to note is that you should not check for profile names or specific general permissions (e.g. View Setup or Modify All Data). Instead, create a permission set that includes access to the page/class/etc and/or a Custom Permission that has to be assigned in order to access sensitive data. This gives the administrators the ability to assign permission to the app to others in their org without giving administrative permissions to that user.